# How to clear message error that occur from the Corda flow test

Tags: corda

I try to run the test that I created from Corda 3.3 in Corda 4.1
I have 2 test case for test the flow
in the first test I expected fail that came from contract 
and the result from first test is also correct as I expected to

but I error that I got from first test was send to hospital flow
and the error have been shown in the second test

actually the error that come for the first test not effect to the second test but it make the second test to slow

I really don't know how to clear the the error message before sun the second test

If someone have any idea please let me know thank you.

Note: If you have the way that not stop the nodes and re-create mock node again before run new test, it will be the solution that I looking for.

[image: .]

==============================

I have 6 tests in one file

first I try to create the network and use that net work for all of 6 test in this way I can reduce the time for initiate the network
but I need to clear the database after each test finish for avoid create duplicate data.

everything work until I change to Corda 4.1

in the 4.1 I don't know why the way that I use for clear database in Corda 3.3 not work like before (In 4.1 take long times for tuncate the table)
so I need to change the way to create the network and stop after finish each test.
In this way take more time for initiate the network (around 20-30 seconds per test)
and the point that surprised me is when I finish 5 tests in the 6th test take the long time (the log show house keeper clean) they use 6 minutes for finished
but when I run only that test, they use 1 minute for finished.
my question are
1. How I clear everything after finish each test
2. Have another way for initiate the network and use for every test? and how to clear the database and message after finish each test

Comment: This image is not helpful. If there is an error, there will also be a stacktrace that tells you what is wrong.

Comment: @DanNewton the error is not my concern, because in my test I expected the error, I add the image for show first the error from previous case come in the current and second I want to show the time that I use for each test

Answer (score 0):

It is not visible actual cause of exception.

But be aware that for 4.x corda you have to put

```
subFlow(ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession))
```

As last operation.
Dunno if this helps

Comment: Maybe the test 1 flow is called again during the test of hospital flow

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are sharing state between tests, which is generally bad. Consider creating a `MockNetwork` in JUnit's `@Before` method or use the `DriverDSL` to create an isolated test for each test case.

Comment: actually I don't plan to share the state between the test, and I don't know how to use DriverDSL, I add more detail to explain my problem in my question. thank you for your help